# Cannot create file in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I have a Unix Aix Server which I log in.

When i try to create a file using `touch filename.txt` I get an error saying :

```
touch: 0652-046 Cannot create filename.txt
```

I have executed id and ls -lad . commands and posted the results:

```
Response of id : uid=290975(gaara) gid=10(audit)
Response of ls -lad . : drwxr-xr-x    2 sigadmin student  256 Jan 11 05:57 .
```

Comment: i guess you don't have writing permission on current folder. What `ls -ald .` says?

Comment: @Davide Berra:It gives two files present in the directory along with . and .. file

Comment: Post output of `id` and `ls -lad .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check file permissions.

```
ls -lad .
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 user group 4096 Jan 11 11:26 .
```

Those permissions indicate `rwx` (user) `rwx` (group) and `r-x` (others). I.e only `user` and `group` can create files in this directory (w=write permission).

Compare these to you own UID/GIDs.

```
id
```

In your case the directory is owned by `sigadmin`. Group `student` and `others` have no permission to create in this directory (r-x). **So it's not supposed to work, since `sigadmin` is the only one having permissions to write in this directory.**

Comment: It gives two files present in the directory along with . and .. file.   I know that its not a faultly disk and there is eneough space coz I can create files with another login-id

Comment: Then it is a permission problem most likely. Check my updated post. Do you know how to interpret basic UNIX-permissions?

Comment: How do i compare the results if id command to my own UID/GIDs.When i run the id command I get the response as uid=290975(gaara) gid=10(audit). What does this mean

Comment: Post output of `id` and `ls -lad .` It'll be easier to see then.

Comment: Posted the results in the question.

Answer (score 0):

might be donot have permission to create a file on that filesystem.
check the directory previleges.check who all have the write permissions in that directory.

Comment: How to check to which group my userid belongs to.

Comment: You can use the `id` command

Comment: I get the response as uid=290975(gaara) gid=10(audit). What does this mean.